# Bamboo and Performance Center integration

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

We are looking for Bamboo and Performance Center integration solution. Please let us know the plugins used for integration or anyone has created code for integration Bamboo and Performance Center.

Or how to create batch job to trigger a load test in Performance Center?

Comment: From the Help Centre: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam_.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to integrate [Bamboo with PC](https://community.microfocus.com/t5/LoadRunner-Performance-Center/Performance-Center-and-Continuous-integration-using-Atlassian-s/ba-p/1639001).